# How to enable drag for transparent AnchorPane?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I need to make my bottom `AnchorPane` transparent, and I used below code to do that. It works, but after that I cannot move my application by drag?

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/DashBoardForm.fxml"));
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

I cannot move application around the workspace; how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this example

```
    public class Demo extends Application {

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    double sceneX = 0;
    double sceneY = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        var button = new Button("button");
        var background = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("#FFB5C5"), new CornerRadii(15), new Insets(0)));
        anchorPane.setBackground(background);
        anchorPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.valueOf("#912CEE"), BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(15), new BorderWidths(2), new Insets(0))));

        button.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
        });

        button.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            var sceneX = event.getSceneX();
            var sceneY = event.getSceneY();
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button, sceneX - x);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, sceneY - y);
        });

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 100.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button, 100.0);
        var scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        scene.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#ffffff00"));

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            sceneX = event.getSceneX() - primaryStage.getX();
            sceneY = event.getSceneY() - primaryStage.getY();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - sceneX);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - sceneY);
        });

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFx");
        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(800);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But I think there will be a better way

Comment: link only answers are strongly discouraged (external references tend to fade away with time) - please post the code here

Comment: Consider using a translucent color for `background`, e.g. `FFB5C57F`.

Comment: See also [_Drag an undecorated Stage with the mouse_](https://blog.samirhadzic.com/2016/09/16/drag-an-undecorated-stage-with-the-mouse/).

Comment: @kleopatra is correct, but a link to your [repository](https://github.com/shanghua521/javafx-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/wang/javafx/demo/Demo.java), in addition to the working example, will allow future visitors to see updates as your code evolves.

Comment: @trashgod This method is great, thank you